# Filter PowerApp BrowseGallery with ComboBox and Text

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-formula

I have a list of assets in the format as below:

```
Site, IP Address, HostName, ...
```

Column "site" is a ComboBox.

I am trying to build an app that allows users to filter by site, and still be able to text search asset by Hostname or IP

So far I have

```
SortByColumns(
If(CountRows(ComboBox1.SelectedItems)=0||IsBlank(ComboBox1.SelectedItems),Filter(
    [@'AssetList'], 
    (StartsWith('IP Address', TextSearchBox1.Text) || StartsWith(Hostname, TextSearchBox1.Text))
), Filter([@'AssetList'], Site in ComboBox1.SelectedItems.Value))
, "IP_x0020_Address", If(SortDescending1, Descending, Ascending))
```

But it only works if nothing is filtered in comboBox. How do I achieve both filter AND combobox

Answer (score 0):

```
SortByColumns(
    If(
        CountRows(ComboBox1.SelectedItems)=0||IsBlank(ComboBox1.SelectedItems),
        Filter(
            [@'AssetList'], 
            (StartsWith('IP Address', TextSearchBox1.Text) || StartsWith(Hostname, TextSearchBox1.Text))
        ), 
        Filter(
            [@'AssetList'], 
            Site in ComboBox1.SelectedItems.Value,
            (StartsWith('IP Address', TextSearchBox1.Text) || StartsWith(Hostname, TextSearchBox1.Text))
        )
    ), 
    "IP_x0020_Address", 
    If(SortDescending1, Descending, Ascending)
)
```

You just needed to add your search box StartsWith functions to your 'ComboBox.Selected items = false' filter statement